# friends dialog 500 error after confirm

Tags: facebook, dialog

Using the friend dialog, friend request works as expected, but when using the same dialog when  the target already maid a friend request, the user is asked to "confirm" which is the expected behavior. However after I hit the confirm button I get a 500 error.

I am pretty sure that my *redirect_url* is correct because, 1. it works when issuing a friend request to an user that didn't already make one, 2. when I change it to an invalid one, it fail with the appropriate message saying the redirect_uri is not owned with *show_error* param to true.
I provide all the required parameters *app_id* and *id*.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends?redirect_uri=<url encoded redirect uri>&id=<target user id>&app_id=<my app id>
```

I spent a day already trying to debug this by myself, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems there is a bug or the documentation is out of date http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/264873186891095

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that multiple meta tags are not sent to Facebook.
For eg, if your page already has meta tags for Fb as properties, you will not ave to specify meta tags in your Fb.ui function call.

And introduce a ChannelUrl option in your init function to avoid further errors.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem. Facebook will analyse your page before sending a link, if it cant, it will throw a 500 error.

**More info:**

If your page does not return a 200 code, it will not analyse your page, and will throw up a 500 error.

Make sure the page you link does not redirect to any other pages, even if they are within your app. A redirect is 3xx code - which is not accepted by facebook.